# d3js version 3 to 4 for toggling barcharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get this old version barchart toggle to work with version 4. I'm also looking to reduce its reliance on underscore - is there a vanilla js version to handle the filtering/sorting of the data for the toggling of the legend?

[image]

version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/xhgew00y/16/

version 4 - current migration
https://jsfiddle.net/q6vu27w3/2/

The current example isn't rendering though.

I've changed `d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBand`, but the conversion may not be correct.

v3

```
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
```

v4

```
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain([0, width])

var x1 = d3.scaleBand();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the changes in your code for it to work in version 4.

1. scaleBand() works for numeric range only.For Strings range(colour), we should use d3.scaleOrdinal() instead of d3.scaleBand().

   ```
    var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f", "#8bf41b"]);
   ```
2. Next, in x0 declaration, it is not domain that you're specifying, that is range and also the rangeRoundBand() is converted to rangeRound().padding() in version 4. So x0 declaration becomes

   ```
   var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
       .rangeRound([0, width])
       .padding(0.1);
   ```
3. Then barGroups variable should be changed from

   ```
   var barGroups = chartHolder.selectAll("g.bars")
   .data(data);
   ```

   to

   ```
   var barGroups = chartHolder.selectAll("g.bars")
           .data(data)
           .enter().append("g")
           .attr("class", "bars")
           .attr("transform", function(d) {
               return "translate(" + x0(d.label) + ",0)";
           });
   ```
4. Then barEnter variable also should be changed from

   ```
   var barEnter = barGroups.selectAll("rect")
           .data(function(d) {
               return d.valores.filter(function(k) { return !k.hidden; }) ;
           });
   ```

   to

   ```
   var barEnter = barGroups.selectAll("rect")
           .data(function(d) {
               return d.valores.filter(function(k) { return !k.hidden; }) ;
           })
           .enter().append("rect").attr('height', 0).attr('y', height).attr('x', 0).attr('width', 0).style('fill',function(d, i) {
           return colorScale(d.name); //colores_google(i);
       });
   ```

   to apply animation to all appended rect elements.

If these changes are done,Then Bar chart in version 4 will work properly.

_.findWhere() can be replaced by

```
Array.prototype.getIndexBy = function (name, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i][name] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then in toggleBar() function you can just do:

```
data.forEach(function(d) { 
   var d.filteredValores = d.valores[d.valores.getIndexBy("hidden", state)];
});
```

Now filteredValores property consists of valores that satisfies the given state.We can then retreive name from that filtered property.Hope this helps.

Comment: you have a jsfiddle for it?